# TypeError: is not a function TypeScript

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have a very simple class like:

```
export class Party {
    constructor(
        public id:Identifier,
        public partyName: PartyName,
        public person:Person
    ) {  }

    copy():Party {
        let copyParty = new Party(this.id, null, null);
        return copyParty;
    }
}
```

I want to use the copy function (or method?) in another class (specifically a service) importing this class like:

```
... (party => {
let copyParty:Party = party.copy();
...
```

But I get the following exception:

```
EXCEPTION: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: party.copy is not a function
```

I tried `let copyParty:Party = Function.call(party.copy, copy)` (got some exceptions) as well as `let copyParty:Party = party.copy;` (returns the function definition, not the copied the object).

What am I missing here?
Thanks.

Comment: my guess is that the `party` you get, is not an instantiated `Party` object. Where does it come from?

Comment: If you type your argument `(party:Party => )` it will help you track down why a party object is not being passed in.

Comment: @PierreDuc the `party` instance is passed by `.then(res => (res.json() as Party[])[0])` block of a REST call

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You cannot use type hinting as actual casting an object to a certain type. It's just used to keep the compiler happy, and your code readable.

You should actually instantiate the objects after the REST call:

```
.then(res => res.json().map(party => new Party(party.id, party.partyName, party.person))[0]
```

This way you get an object which has the `copy` method